# Coinbase API using Python (PyCharm)

Tags: python, api, coinbase-api

I am trying to use Coinbase's API to get my wallet info to eventually make transactions using Python. Below is the 2 lines of code that i have written:

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
```

After running, I get the error--> 'NameError: name 'api_key' is not defined'.
I know that I am supposed to set up an API Key and API Secret via Coinbase (which I have done already) and even put them both in the 'Client' parenthesis. Cany anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or guide me to successfully use my Coinbase API in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you initialize both vars before creating the client

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
api_key = 'my api key here'
api_secret = 'my api secret'
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
```

The error specifically tells you that `api_key` is not defined

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory, your variable `api_key` and `api_secret` are undefined, thus the `NameError` exception.

1. What you can is replace `api_key` by hardcoding your key and secret
   provided by Coinbase (it should be in the form of a long randomly
   generated string)
2. Verify that you can indeed perform an API call on Coinbase
3. Now, remove the hardcoded version and use environment variables instead (this will prevent you from publishing your keys to public repositories by mistakes) [How to use environment variables for API keys](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-keep-your-secret-keys-safe-secure-8b1a7877d69c)

Comment: Thanks man. I know this is a cringe worthy question but I am a noob.